# How to give a python client a port number from a python server

Tags: python, network-programming, client-server, port, server

I'm trying to build a simple python server that a client can connect to without the client having to know the exact portnumber. Is that even possible? The thought is to choose a random portnumber and using it for clients to connect.

I know you could use bind(host, 0) to get a random port number and socket.getsockname()[1] within the server to get my portnumber. But how could my client get the portnumber?

I have tried socket.getnameinfo() but I don't think I understand how that method really works.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that the server must listen on a certain port(s).
This means the client(s) will need to interact on these ports with it.

So... no it is impossible to do that on some random unknown port.

Answer (score 0):

You need to advertise the port number somehow. Although DNS doesn't do that (well, you could probably cook up some resource record on the server object, but that's not really done) there are many network services that do. LDAP like active directory (you need write rights), DNS-SD dns service discovery, universal plug and play, service location protocol, all come to mind. You could even record the port number on some web page somewhere and have the client read it.

Comment: but that's not random...the client wants to connect on a random port

Comment: @c0deMonk3y - The client doesn't connect to a random port. The server selects a port randomly and then advertises it. The client reads the advertisement and connects quite specifically to the one port given by the server.

Comment: This may very well be how it works traditionally. However OP asked about a client that does not know on which port the server listens to.

Comment: @c0deMonk3y -yes you are quite right. OP asked "But how could my client get the portnumber" and my answer is that the server advertises the port number through one of many networking service resolvers that do such a thing. I have no idea what you mean by "how it works traditionally".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Zeroconf, it seems to be the path to where you are trying to get to.